# How would I replace variable names in list with values?

Tags: python

I have two variables as follows:

```
a = "1"
b = "21"
```

and a list:

```
['a', 'b', '3', '4', '5', '64']
```

How would I go about replacing variable names with their values in the list, like:

```
['1', '21', '3', '4', '5', '64']
```

Comment: Dynamically, or in your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you don't mean the fact you just need to give the name of the variable, not as a string?

You could do a "monstrosity" such as:

```
a = '1'
b = '21'

els = ['a', 'b', '3', '4', '5', '64']
print [vars().get(el, el) for el in els]
# ['1', '21', '3', '4', '5', '64']
```

But if you're in a situation that you're doing that, or thinking of doing that -- it's time to think again

Answer (score 1):

First construct a dictionary for lookup?

```
lookup = {'a':'1', 'b':'21'}
```

Then you are good to go:

```
print [lookup[x] if x in lookup else x for x in c ]
['1', '21', '3', '4', '5', '64']
```

Comment: `[lookup.get(x, x) for x in c]` is better

Answer (score 0):

You only have to remove the quotes:

```
a = "1"
b = "21"
[a, b, "3", "4", "5", "64"]
```

The output would be `["1", "21", "3", "4", "5", "64"]`

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the other answers, you could use [`eval`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval) if the variables names must exist as strings in the list.  For your example, the following code:

```
eval(list[0])
```

would evaluate to 1 (provided `list` is the variable for your list).

You have to be careful though, because if the variable does not exist, it will throw a `NameError`, and if you do not pass a string, byte, or code object, it will throw a `TypeError`.